# Java finds a "Documents and Settings" folder on Win 7 HP. I can't see one

Tags: java, windows-7, recursion, directory

In Java, I am trying to list the files and folders in my `C:\` directory and loop through them using:
`File[] files = new File("C:\\").listFiles();`

However, to my surprise when I loop through the array I find that the first index is `C:\Documents and Settings`! For a starters, I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium and I haven't even upgraded from Windows XP or anything but no matter what I do I can not see this folder on my drive, dispite choosing to view hidden folders!?

Furthermore, as you would suspect, when you start to use a recursive method to look through every folder on the drive it throws a `NullPointerException` as soon as it tries to list the files in that directory.

Does anyone know why this is, or even better how to solve the issue? Any idea's appreciated, thanks in advance

---

UPDATE: I've now very quickly established that `C:\Documents and Settiings` is a *symlink* or *"JUNCTION"*, so know by question is: how do I determine that it is a symlink in Java so that I can tell the for loop to skip any?

Comment: It's in general a REALLY bad idea to follow symlinks while traversing directories. If you want to do that you have to make sure to detect cycles, otherwise you'll end up in an endless loop. Most tools in unix (where symlinks are seen much more often) by default ignore them..

Comment: Ah, so it's a symlink. That was actually part of my question - I couldn't understand why it was appearing in the array generated by `listFiles()` but I couldn't see it in Windows Explorer. Please see my amended question.

Comment: The original java file API was severely limited and rather deficient in lots of different ways - I'm not sure how you'd do it with that. The new Java7 File API is much improved and allows you to specify options on how symlinks should be handled: [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html)

Comment: Thanks Voo. Please see my comment on @schtever's answer though

Comment: Clearly a rights problem, the Documents and Settings folder has some extremely restricted access rights and isSymbolicLink states: `false if the file [...] cannot be determined if the file is a symbolic link or not.`. You should first check whether you can even read the file: `Files.isReadable(file)` will return false for you there. Made an answer out of this post :)

Comment: @Voo I like the 'Clearly' - that didn't even cross my mind. Maybe given more time it would have though. Anyway, thanks for your answer - you posted just in time, I was about to give up testing and just use the try catch block to 'sort things out'. I guess that's another arkward thing about Windows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think this warrants a full answer here. There are several things going on at once here which makes it a bit more interesting than on first glance.

Yes `Documents and Settings` is a symlink under Vista+, no that's not the problem we have here. The real problem is that the folder has some extremely restricted access rights - by default not even Admins have access to it.

If we read the `isSymbolicLink` javadoc it clearly states:

> false if [...] cannot be determined if the file is a symbolic
>   link or not

Since we don't have any rights to access the directory we cannot determine whether it is a symbolic link or not. But since we then try to access the file anyhow we get an exception telling us we can't access the file.

Hence the correct check should look something like this:

```
if (!Files.isReadable(file) || Files.isSymbolicLink(file)) continue;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply AND Thank god you posted a full answer - thanks a bunch! Of course it makes sense to check that Java can read the folder first - even if it was a symbolic link, if Java doesn't even have sufficient permissions there's no point in trying; now I feel stupid that I didn't even give that a thought! Once again thank you, I think this question has been quite useful on my than one count. PS Needless to say that it's now working/ignores such folders perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

On my Windows 7 system, "Documents and Settings" is a JUNCTION to Users.  Your code should probably check to see if the directory entry is a not a real directory.

To see it on your system, do a "DIR /AS C:\" from the command window.  You should see something like:

```
07/14/09  00:08    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
```

Comment: Okay, that's interesting, so what would you suggest I do in order to remedy the Java code and prevent it from treating this *"JUNCTION"* as a directory to recurse?

Comment: As mentioned above, use the Java nio package and try the Files.isSymbolicLink method.

Comment: I have implemented the `Files.isSymbolicLink()` method but for some reason it's not detecting `C:\Documents and Settings` as a symbolic link! My `if` statement to continue looks like `if(Files.isSymbolicLink(folder.toPath() && ... )` and if the else block just skips that loop!

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. Even though I didn't accept your answer because I felt that @Voo's was more complete etc, you did point me in the right direction very quickly which was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think when you use Windows 7 in another language than english it translates the folder names in the explorer but the name in the file system stays the same. If you are using another language look for the folder with the name it would be in your language. If not, never mind.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm using Windows 7 in English. Nice to know though.